# Is there a term that covers body parts, tools, entities and more?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to design a concept for a Trading Card Game and I've got this thing thought out, but I'm unsure how to name it.

The concept:

> Creatures can be divided into several parts that can be independently destroyed when a creature enters combat.

A few examples of these parts that make up a creature are the following:

- *Orc with Spear*, consists of *Orc* and *Spear*
- *Bear*, consists of *Head*, *Body* and *Legs*
- *Mechanized Bear*, consists of *Head*, *Body*, *Legs*, *Armor* and *Rocket Launcher*

As you can see sometimes every part referred is a whole entity, sometimes it's a body part and sometimes it is an attachment or a tool.

I've come up with the following names, but none of them quite cuts it:

- Part
- Piece
- Component
- Modification

Someone also suggested me to use *Fragment*, while it sounds really cool, I'm not quite sure how I can justify that it means something like a part, a piece, etc.

Is there a word that covers what I mean?

Comment: What about *element*: a fundamental, essential, or irreducible constituent of a composite entity. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/element

Comment: *Component* and *part* are perfectly fine. *Piece* is too generic. *Fragment* does not really work. *Modification* does not work at all. But why not say *target*? When you can target a creature in various different places and destroy the targets independently, then well, they are *targets*.

Comment: *Target* leaves a lot of room for sillyness. If I *targeted* your spear with my rocket launcher, would it really make sense to only destroy your spear?

Comment: Can you, uh, recycle bits? Or build creatures from different cards? Because if it's just to destroy something, "target" would do just fine.

Comment: @RegDwigнt The player can most likely not target what part they want to destroy, so I'm not sure if it then still fits.

Comment: "Constituent" is a synonym for component.  Maybe you would prefer that?

Comment: A unit? (single thing, person or group, which is part of a larger entity)

Answer (score 1):

So we can say that your creatures might be destroyed ***piecemeal***?

American Heritage dictionary 3rd ed.

adj.  Accomplished or made in stages.

adv.  By a small amount at a time; in phases; one part at a time.

Piece by piece; by degrees; unsystematic or random partial measures taken over a period of time.

For the components or add-ons perhaps:

**facets; aspects; assets; composites; increments; fractions**

Comment: +1 If you would like to add 'unit' to your answer, you are welcome to do so:)

Answer (score 0):

If this were [MTG](https://www.google.com/search?q=mtg&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), the orc would always be a **creature** and the spear either a **token** or an **artifact**.

The mechanized bear might be an **artifact creature** with **tokens** on it.

There is also a subset of artifacts called **equipment**.

To describe that "even more" part, all of these things are considered **permanents**.

---

Now that that's out of the way, the only new thing I'm seeing here is to be able to split lifeforms into body parts. Build your own chimera type stuff. I like *part* for this. Or get real specific like *hing legs*, *mandibles*, ect. because I'd assume you'd have to state in the rules *"only one per type of augmentation is allowed"*. Ah, there it is:

## **augmentation**

> noun; something that augments –[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/augmentation)

augment /ôɡˈment/verb –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=augmentation%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=augment)

> make (something) greater by adding to it; increase.

Answer (score -1):

The unassuming word, "PORTION(S)" in gaming world with verbs like --- 'strike, hit, thawck' to join or disjoin--- can convey the concept of whole of the stuff the item of any description is made of.

The word, "STUFF" may be a fair candidate in the race as it means "the tangible substance that goes into the make up of physical object" but dropped on the ground that it sounds odd if applied to human limbs.